# Azure Notification Hub's Expiration Date

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

When I view my **Azure Notification Hub**'s device registry, it has a column called **Expiration Date**. My question is, what happens to the registry after the expiration date? Do clients get notified that their notification hub registry will expire and will need to register with GCM and notification hub again in order to receive future notifications?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

GCM will NOT automatically make device to refresh the token. In other words, If your app at the device does not up and running nor being updated until the expiration date, the push message will not be delivered.

Similar discussion can be found at here: [Do GCM registration id's expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590482/do-gcm-registration-ids-expire)

In the view of Azure Notification Hub, Azure also does not have mechanism to make token refresh forcefully, but you can make a worker role to list them up and re-register by sending push message to target devices.

For that, related post can be found at here: [Azure Notification Hubs registration time to live (90 days limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823813/azure-notification-hubs-registration-time-to-live-90-days-limit)

Comment: Hi, I think GCM does make device refresh token.
By using tokenRefreshed
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#keeping-the-registration-state-in-sync

Comment: @LeoChen // no it doesn't. your link said that *you should periodically initiate token refresh from the server*, which means we programmer make token refresh by ourselves. `TokenRefreshed` is just an received event after the token is refreshed successfully or not.